# Webcam integration in asp.net with the help free apis

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

i'm currrently looking for a solution which is integrate webcam (at client side) with my web application that programmed . i need to detect client webcam and then stream the capturing video from the webcam to my web application and then allow them to capture image by clicking button on my web application.

Plz help your prevoius topics also didn't helped.Plz provide me a sample application for this.The ApI to be used.

Answer (score 0):

I think as you should have seen from the previous answers, there aren't any **free** api's that allow you do this.

You'll need a Flash object to interact with the web cam, talking to a Flash Communication Server to capture the video, and go from there.

> Search SO for [[asp.net] webcam](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=asp.net+webcam)